# HTML 5 audio tag not streaming, but instead collecting until server closes

Tags: html, audio, flask, stream, buffering

I have written a server that streams RTP data in response to a GET request.
Oddly enough, it will collect the audio data but play it once the server turns off. I am transferring over live recordings, this is not feasible and I need it to be played immediately.

```
<audio src="http://localhost:5000/test.wav" controls autoplay>
  <p>If your browser doesn't support the 'audio' element, it will display the content here between the opening and closing tags.</p>
</audio>
```

Here is the current implementation of the client side code. I have an example of when this works too from a demo I found online.

```
<audio src="http://www.html.am/resources/sample.mp3" controls>
  <p>If your browser doesn't support the 'audio' element, it will display the content here between the opening and closing tags.</p>
  </audio>
```

Why is it collecting the data and playing it once the connection is finished, am I forgetting something?

Here it the server side code written using flask.

```
class wavFileStream(Resource):

    def gen(self):
        global 20_ms_audio

        yield self.createWAVEHeader()

        while True:
              yield 20_ms_audio

    def get(self):
        return Response(self.gen(), mimetype='audio/wav',
                        direct_passthrough=True)
```

Edit :

It works in firefox, not chrome.